NuGet and LGPL libraries
We're creating software written on the .NET platform.
As such, we're obviously heavily reliant on the NuGet package manager.
Some of these packages are LGPL (2.1, 3) licensed. As this other question explains we are not only required to provide the information that we use these libraries, and comply with their other terms, but also to provide the source code "from the same place":

offer equivalent access to the Corresponding Source in the same way
through the same place at no further charge

However, NuGet does not provide the source code for a given package. At best it offers a link to a public repository, and at the very best it also offers a link with a commit ID to actually determine what the correct/exact corresponding source code for a given nuget package actually is -- which is not very common as of writing this.
So, if we then distribute our software in binary form, it would seem:
To comply with the LGPL we must:

provide the source code to these (unmodified) nuget libraries
and we must do so "from the same place" as we provide our software
The source package/link we provide must be the exact source version of the nuget library we use

That means, that, for each and every LGPL package we reference, our engineering team must determine the exact source code version used to build the corresponding package. Then zip that up and make it available as part of our software distribution process. Even though our Devs themselves never ever interact with the source code of these packages.
Is this analysis correct?
Does anybody actually do this? :-) (in the .NET world)

Are you modifying the NuGet (or other LGPL) libraries at all, or are you simply distributing a combined work based on both your code and those libraries?  If the latter, are the LGPL libraries statically or dynamically linked in?

@MadHatter - nothing is modified. Everything is dynamically linked.

"Does anybody actually do this?" - Would you like a list of every major Linux distribution package manager and how they offer (typically) a corresponding "-dev" package for each program? I believe pre-compiled Python packages in PIP and R packages at CRAN typically do this as well. At first glance, it looks to me like NuGet.org is just not as dilligent about this. It's also possible that some people believe that supplying the source code is only required in case the LGPL library is modified. Personally I don't believe that (from the other Answer), but I understand why one might think that.

It's also possible NuGet was just not thinking about this from the beginning. It seems they only added a "source code" linking property in the .nupkg format as of Aug 2018. Of course, such a property is required to comply with LGPL, but it would have made it a lot easier, since this seems to directly fulfill the requirement for "clear directions next to the object code saying where to find the Corresponding Source".

"for each and every LGPL package we reference" -- Are you only "referencing" the LGPL code, or do you actually include the object code in your package (i.e. is it inside the .nupkg file when one downloads it)? I think this makes a difference.

@Brandin - with my exclamation of "is anybody doing this" my intention was to refer to the .NET/nuget ecosystem. (I also had C++ package managers like vcpkg and conan.io in mind, but I don't know these as well so I did not comment on that)

@Brandin - "... is it inside the .nupkg file when one downloads it?" - The users do not download our code as nupkg, the would download the software as a zip of binaries or a Windows installer or possibly (hypothetically) a .deb package - in which case, yes, the object code will be included in the downloaded package.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


Is this analysis correct?

I don't think so, no.  You are not obliged to provide the source of libraries you use under LGPL unless you modify them (LGPLv3 s2).  There are also source provision requirements in LGPLv3 s4d0, but since you're using dynamic linking, s4d1 applies, which has no such requirements.
Edit: I hadn't intended to do the analysis for LGPLv2.1, but since it's arising in comments, here's my take on it.  s6 begins

As an exception to the Sections above, you may also combine or link a "work that uses the Library" with the Library to produce a work containing portions of the Library, and distribute that work under terms of your choice

So you may take a work formed by linking the LGPL library with your own code, and distribute it under terms of your choice, without being bound by ss1-5 inclusive.  This is subject to meeting one of certain conditions laid out in s6, and as I say, the OP meets s6b.
So any argument that LGPLv2.1 doesn't permit this will need to be based on ss7-16 inclusive, and I don't see anything therein that would cause the OP a problem.

Does this analysis "only obliged to provide the source of libraries you use under LGPL unless you modify them" also apply for LGPL 2.1? I can see how you would reach this conclusion when reading LGPL3 alone, when one reads s4d1, and reaches the conclusion you have here. But even LGPL3 has s4b (Accompany the library with the GPL3 document), and although it doesn't say it here, I think the intention was that you also have to "comply" with the plain GPL3 with respect to that thing you are including; the GPL3 document is really where the "corresponding source" requirement ultimately lies.

LGPLv2.1 s6 exempts the user from s4, which is the normal source provision requirement, provided one of the conditions in s6 is met.  One of those is indeed source provision (s6a), but since the OP is using dynamic linking (s)he satisfies s6b, and therefore does not need to provide library source.  You may believe that persons distributing combined works based on dynamically-linked unmodified LGPL libraries still have a source provision requirement for those libraries, but I can't see that they do.

I'm not sure if this analysis will hold water for LGPL 2.1. In particular, the sentence "Hereinafter, translation is included without limitation in the term 'modification'." It basically means, that if you compiled something yourself, then you have 'modified' it in LGPL 2.1 terms. The same may hold true for LGPL 3 + GPL 3, but analyzing that is more complicated because the two documents go together. Of course, in any case, if you literally just copy a pre-compiled binary from somewhere else (e.g. qt.io) and distribute that, then of course you can claim that you didn't modify it.

My analysis for LGPLv2.1 is not based on anything of the sort, it's based on ss1-5 being disapplied by s6.  See edit above for more details.
